# CloudKit CKModifyRecordsOperation Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I am using CKModifyRecordsOperation to batch create about 8000 records in CloudKit. However, I am getting a strange error for about 5% of the records: `record to insert already exists`. I have been unable to figure out why this occurs after thorough investigation and retesting. Notes to consider:

1. The db is completely empty at start.
2. I create a recordName locally for each record using the method `[NSUUID UUID].UUIDString`. During retesting I have also confirmed that there are no duplicate recordNames by creating a set of recordNames and comparing its count to the count of total records to upload.
3. I have verified that each record is only uploaded only once by adding a counter to the the batch upload operation to compare the total record count pre-upload.
4. All records are properly uploaded (compared counts in CloudKit to total records upload) - so unsure why the "errors" are occurring.

Any ideas as to why these errors are being generated please?

Code:

```
- (void)uploadInitialRecordsToCloudKit:(NSArray *)recordsToUpload {

    NSArray *recordsForThisBatch = recordsToUpload;
    NSArray *remainingRecords = nil;

    if ([recordsToUpload count] > 350) recordsForThisBatch = [recordsToUpload subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 350)];
    remainingRecords = [recordsToUpload subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([recordsForThisBatch count], [recordsToUpload count] -[recordsForThisBatch count])];

    CKModifyRecordsOperation *modifyRecordsOperation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:recordsForThisBatch recordIDsToDelete:nil];
    modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable savedRecords, NSArray<CKRecordID *> * _Nullable deletedRecordIDs, NSError * _Nullable operationError) {

        if (operationError) NSLog(@"Error during batch save to CK: %@\n\n%@", [operationError localizedDescription], operationError.userInfo);
        else NSLog(@"Batch upload to CK successful");

        if ([remainingRecords count] > 0) [self uploadInitialRecordsToCloudKit:remainingRecords];

    };

    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase] addOperation:modifyRecordsOperation];

}
```

Comment: Edit your question with relevant code showing how you use the operation and how you do error handling.

Comment: 8000/350 = 22.8 ? Are you sure there isn't some sort of overlap with the .8 batch of records to upload?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a CloudKit issue as the third test completed without any errors.